laravel vite not working tailwind css in shared hosting
enter image description here
here my repo
https://github.com/madfortech/PersonalApp
my question is Laravel vite have problem on shared hosting. working on localhost well but when live some class not working on shared hosting help me
how will i fix  my browser source code
 // when i click this link 404 error how i solve
